# How do I set my source path for STS/Eclipse (using Groovy grails) and make it stick?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I debug a Groovy/Grails program in STS, the first time in a session that it hits a breakpoint it asks me where the source code is.

[image]

When I click on that dialog, I need to add my "Project" and then it will work until I exit STS and restart.

[image]

(But for DEBUGGING only! Lines of code mentioned in the console, whether or not they're displayed as links, will NEVER display the source when clicked on.)

1)  How do I make it remember it forever? I looked through all the properties/settings I could find.

And

2) How can I click on an line of code that's mentioned in the console window (say an Exception) and have it automatically go to that line? (Micsosoft Visual Studio will do it...and it's never had to ask me where my source code is. In my 15 years of using it....)

Not everything gets hyperlinked, and even when it does, it will never find the source code, even though I can navigate to it in the Project or Package explorers:

[image]

Comment: What version of STS are you using?

Comment: I have never seen this dialog before when debugging a standard Grails application.  Can you post a screenshot of the dialog, or a snippet of the text?

Comment: OK.  Both of your problems appear to have the same cause.  I feel like there must be something a little bit atypical about your grails project setup.  Are you using a recent version of Grails?  Can you reproduce this behavior on a simple one-domain one-controller project?  Are you running on tcServer?  Have you moved any of the default directories from their default location?

Comment: It's grails 1.3.6; I've NEVER had this work, and I've been working with Grails for about a year, dutifully upgrading whenever there's a new version. I've reinstalled STS several times--the latest was a fresh install one week ago--I get the exact same behavior on two different machines I develop on. I haven't moved anything from its default location, and I always use the grails utilites to create new controllers, views, etc; and it happens on more than one project.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask this question on the STS forums: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=32

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the second part of the question here.  If you see a reference to a stack frame in the console window and it is not there is no hyperlink (often the hyperlink exists, but in certain situations it will not be), then you should select and copy the stack trace and paste it into a Java stack trace console:

[image: Java Stack Trace Console]

Comment: The hyperlink exists, but when I click on it, "nothing happens". I'll post a screenshot